# Resetting activity when data cleared

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, reset

I am currently working on an app, but there is a bug in  it. Whenever a user installs the app or clears data, it should get reset. But instead the app fills in standard data for the user, instead of showing the start screen where user can input himself.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    checkFirstRun();
    savedData();

    }

public void savedData() {
    showGoalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    showBeamsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    showGoalEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    checkBtnPressed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    showBeamsEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    beamsGoal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    //Fetch the stored data and display it upon starting.
    String goalSave = showGoalTextView.getText().toString();
    String beamsSave = showBeamsTextView.getText().toString();

    preferences = getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE);

    goalSave = preferences.getString("goals", goalSave);
    beamsSave = preferences.getString("beam", beamsSave);

    showGoalTextView.setText(goalSave);
    showBeamsTextView.setText(beamsSave);

    //Hide all the first use stuff
    showGoalEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    checkBtnPressed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    showBeamsEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    beamsGoal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


public void checkFirstRun() {
    final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    final String PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY = "version_code";
    final int DOESNT_EXIST = -1;

    //Get current version code
    int currentVersionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;

    //Get saved version
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    int savedVersionCode = preferences.getInt(PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY, DOESNT_EXIST);

    //Check for first run or upgrade
    if (currentVersionCode == savedVersionCode) {
        //No big deal
        return;
    } else if (savedVersionCode == DOESNT_EXIST) {
        //TODO This is a new install
        resetAll();
    } else if (currentVersionCode > savedVersionCode) {
        //TODO This is an upgrade
        return;
    }

    //Update sharedPreferences with the current version code
    preferences.edit().putInt(PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY, currentVersionCode).apply();
}

public void resetAll() {
    //For when resetting
    TextView showGoalTextView =
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    EditText showGoalEditText =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ImageButton checkBtnPressed =
            (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    EditText showBeamsEditText =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    EditText beamsGoal =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    //Clear editTexts
    showGoalEditText.getText().clear();
    showBeamsEditText.getText().clear();

    //Show all editTexts
    showGoalEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    checkBtnPressed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    showBeamsEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    beamsGoal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //Get the text view
    TextView showResetTextView =
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    //Get the value of the text view
    String resetString = showResetTextView.getText().toString();

    //Convert value to a number and reset it
    Integer reset = Integer.parseInt(resetString);
    reset = 0;

    //Display the new value in the text view.
    showResetTextView.setText(reset.toString());
    showGoalTextView.setText("BEAMS");
}
```

My question is mainly on the `checkFirstRun` method.
I want to input:

`} else if (savedVersionCode == DOESNT_EXIST) {
        //TODO This is a new install
        resetAll();`

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. Can anyone point out the issue at hand?

Comment: If it is a new install, how can there be data to fill? If it's a reinstall, then `if (currentVersionCode == savedVersionCode) {` will run

Comment: @LanceToth That is what I was wondering too. When I installed the app from the Play Store on my phone, it hid the `EditText` & `ImageButton`. What do I need to input on:     `} else if (savedVersionCode == DOESNT_EXIST) {
        //TODO This is a new install` if I want to prevent this? I thought `resetAll();` would take care of it.

Comment: SharedPreferences is persistent between installs, might that be the problem?

Comment: True, it is useful when I push updates, so the user's data persists. I thought it didn't persist when a user uninstalls the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharedPreferences is not cleared with uninstall (at least, not since Marshmallow). This might help you solve it [SharedPreferences are not being cleared when I uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517239/sharedpreferences-are-not-being-cleared-when-i-uninstall)

Comment: Ah, I see. So this means `checkFirstRun()` is useless, am I right?

Comment: Not if you want to check for version changes

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed `android:allowBackup="false"` in my `Manifest.xml`, which I think solves the problem. Which makes me think there is a mistake in my `savedData()`, because it automatically hides the `EditTexts`, even when freshly installing the app. Do I need to make some sort of `if-statement` in the method? I am grateful for your quick answers and help!

Comment: May I ask you how exactly to do that in the `savedData()` part? All my attempts thus far, did not have the expected result. If it is not too much of a hassle of course.

Comment: Simply check if any of the data is there (that's guaranteed to be there)

Comment: Would        `if (goalSave != "Beams") {
            goalSave = preferences.getString("goals", goalSave);
        }` work? Putting it above the `preferences` initiator, but below the `String goalSave = showGoalTextView.getText().toString();`?

Comment: `String goalSave = showGoalTextView.getText().toString();` gets the contents of the field, which I assue is empty anyway. Simply put `if (goalSave != null) {` after `goalSave = preferences.getString("goals");`

Comment: Now I have: `goalSave = preferences.getString("goals", goalSave);
        if (goalSave != null) {
            showGoalTextView.setText(goalSave);
        } else {
            
        }` I assume I need to do the same for beamsSave, only then do `if (beamSave != "0") { showBeamsTextView.setText(beamsSave)`, because the default set value of the `TextView` is 0, but it is converted to string so I can't use an `int`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! I have moved the last piece of my question. You helped me out with the problem as was originally. I owe you!